# how i can change background combobox in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, combobox

Like this http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/62122/460886.aspx

Comment: Don't you have the answer in the link your provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which background you are trying to change, but you can set any background by overriding the `ComboBox`'s ControlTemplate.  Your best bet is probably to copy the default `ComboBox` ControlTemplate from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408%28VS.95%29.aspx) and then modify the necessary background to match your needs.